# os.stat and multiprocessing. analyzing list of files in parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run `os.stat` in `pool`for list of files but as result receive just nested list of files statistics:

```
list_of_files = ['file1.txt','file2.txt','file3.txt']
p = Pool(4) 
list_of_stats = p.map(os.stat, list_of_files)
```

`list_of_fies` contains the next value:
`nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=8905L, st_atime=1499725858L, st_mtime=1416573654L, st_ctime=1445009618L)...`

my question is: what is the simplest way to get the file name + statistics related to this files in list/dict?

for instance dict: 
`{'file1.txt': [st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=8905L, st_atime=1499725858L,...]}`

Comment: `[st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=8905L, st_atime=1499725858L,...]` is a SyntaxError. Did you want something like `dict(zip(list_of_files, list_of_stats))`?

Comment: small clarification. i want to get smth like: `file_name1, [statistics_of_file_name1];file_neme2, [statistics_of_file_name2]` it can be some nested data structure. it needs for analyzing all amounts of files based on modification date or size of file, etc

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution with using the code similar to below:

```
list_of_files = [name1, name2, name3, name4]

def file_stat(file_path):
    return (file_path, os.stat(file_path))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = Pool(2)
    list_of_stats = p.map(file_stat, list_of_files)

    print(type(list_of_stats)) 

    print(list_of_stats)
```

output:

```
<type 'list'>

[(u'\\path\to\file\name1.xml', nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=8905L, st_atime=1501540255L, st_mtime=1416573654L, st_ctime=1445009618L)), (u'\\path\to\file\name2.xml', nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0L, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=47000L, st_atime=1501540327L, st_mtime=1475583701L, st_ctime=1445009618L)), ... ]
```